# Is MVC ajax form support CCS class name for UpdateTargetId instead of elementId?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am trying to performing an action using MVC ajax form. I want to update content with response of action. Like I have two TR tags named with different ids. When I click on a Delete button which present in second TR (TD) then need to replace with both TR(TD) with response of action, is it possible to update content with response of action using a class name?

```
<tr id="EditTR" class="updateclassID">
<td>
@*Some content goes here*@
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="DeletTR" class="updateclassID">
  <td>
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteEntranceType", "Admin", new AjaxOptions
    {
       HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementId = "LoadingID",
        UpdateTargetId = "updateclassID"
      }
     ))
     {
      <p class="alert alert-danger">
        Are you sure want to delete this Entrance permanently. Associated student's exams and their plans also deleted?
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Yes</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="togglesingle('delete-@item.EntranceTypeID')">No</button>
      </p>    
 }
 </td>
 </tr>
```

You can notice I put UpdateTargetId = "updateclassID"  it is a class name of the TR. I want to replace data by class instead of element id.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `OnComplete` property instead:

```
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    LoadingElementId = "LoadingID",
    OnComplete = "updateRows"
 }
```

In JavaScript:

```
function updateRows(data) {
    $('.updateclassID').html(data);
}
```